# Pop Up is not working correctly on iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, popup

I developed a mvc application.I deployed the application on iis. When i tried to click pop up button, i notice that the pop up event returns login page. It was runnig correctly on localhost debug mode.I also tried the log in on pop up window but an error appeared:

> Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'

But i use different connectionstring . Application works on remote sql server and it is running correctly for Index etc.

My pop Up jquery code is:

```
  ShowPopup = function (clicked_id) {
    window.open('/Not/Index/' + clicked_id + '', "PopupWindow", 'width=400px,height=400px,top=150,left=250');
}
```

"Not" is one of my controllers and it is not authorized (allows anonymous)
The Index page that i click a button for pop up event is my the other controller and it authorized.

Why is that happening? Could you please help me?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: If `NotController` doesn't need authorisation, do you have Anonymous enabled in IIS?  [WebSite]->Authentication->Anonymous Authentication:Enabled.   As this works on your local, it's likely to be a server config such as the above.

Comment: yes, anonymous authentication is enabled in IIS  @freedomn-m

Comment: Solved. That's an url string problem